# collecting three ArrayLists into one and viewing it in a custom ListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I am trying to send this ArrayList :

```
all1 = all.toArray(new String[all.size()]);
```

which is a summation of these three array lists parsed from a JSON:

```
for (int j = 0; j < itemNames.size(); j++) {
                all.add(brandNames.get(j) + " " + itemNames.get(j) + " " + Carbs.get(j));
            }
```

to a custom list view but am having trouble setting up the adapter.

I have a custom list view as follows(search_list_view):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<!-- layout child -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Edit button -->
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Text view for main text -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/brandName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Item Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I understand i need a custom adapter and so far i have this but it is not working:

```
private class FoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {


    public FoodAdapter(Context context, List<Food> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    //inflate view layout_list_item
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        //link buttons to views within layout_list_item
        Button btnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        TextView txtMemo = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.brandName);
return convertView;
```

My Model is as follows:

```
public class Food implements Serializable {
//set variables
private Date date;
private String text;
private boolean fullDisplayed;
private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy 'at' hh:mm aaa");
//memo date
public Food() {
    this.date = new Date();
}
//create Food
public Food(long time, String text) {
    this.date = new Date(time);
    this.text = text;
}
//get time
public long getTime() {
    return date.getTime();
}
//set text
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
//get text
public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

//get shortened version of text for not full displayed
public String getShortText() {
    String temp = text.replaceAll("\n", " ");
    if (temp.length() > 25) {
        return temp.substring(0, 25) + "...";
    } else {
        return temp;
    }
}
//set full displayed
public void setFullDisplayed(boolean fullDisplayed) {
    this.fullDisplayed = fullDisplayed;
}
//set flag for if is full displayed
public boolean isFullDisplayed() {
    return this.fullDisplayed;
}
//set a toString method for returning text.
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.text;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does it not display anything on screen? Does it not populate the items with data or .. ?! Does it even enter in getView() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set your data in getView for the TextView. You have to get the data from your list for that position and populate into the TextView using the getText method of your Food class.

Replace your adapter code with the code below:

```
private class FoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {
    private List<Food> mObjects;

    public FoodAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        mObjects = new ArrayList<Food> (objects);
    }

    //inflate view layout_list_item
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        //link buttons to views within layout_list_item
        Button btnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        TextView txtMemo = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.brandName);
    txtMemo.setText(mObjects.get(position).getText());
return convertView;
```

**NOTE**- In the code above while creating the list I've created an ArrayList. List is an interface, when you create an instance you have to create it with a class, like ArrayList or LinkedList. Hence, when you call your adapter pass an ArrayList not a List.